# Will a NTP client work against a SNTP server?

Tags: ntp

SNTP is a simplification of the full NTP specification.

I'd like to use a full NTP client against the internal SNTP server incorporated in Windows XP. Will that work or is a full NTP server required for the NTP client to work?

Comment: I have and it worked but I'm not completely sure that the client I used was a "real" NTP only client or if its implementation includes something specific from SNTP... I was looking more for a technical justification more than a practical one...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the answer in the SNTP RFC 2030:

> SNTP Version 4 is designed to coexist
>   with existing NTP and SNTP Version 3
>   clients and servers, as well as
>   proposed Version 4 clients and
>   servers. When operating with current
>   and previous versions of NTP and SNTP,
>   SNTP Version 4 requires no changes to
>   the protocol or implementations now
>   running or likely to be implemented
>   specifically for NTP ir SNTP Version
>   4. To a NTP or SNTP server, **NTP and SNTP clients are undistinguishable; to
>   a NTP or SNTP client, NTP and SNTP
>   servers are undistinguishable.**

So, yes, it will work.